# Netbeans in wrong setting?

Tags: netbeans

I don't know if I have tampered with the settings on Netbeans but it will not allow me to type any code or read previously written code. I tried uninstalling and re-installing again but no luck! Is this just a setting or do I need to download something else to continue using Netbeans? The homepage never changes from this

[image: this].

Any help at all would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) and update your question with any relevant messages in that log.

Comment: NetBeans [Bug 257070 - File history no available](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257070) may be relevant, though that applied to 8.1, but you are using 8.2. Regardless, try closing the tab for the file you opened that is showing _No history available_, then open that file again. Do you still get that _No history available_, or does it work?